# Plotting derivative of nls model in R

Tags: r, plot, derivative, nls

I have used `nls` function to fit the following equation

```
y ~ (C + (A1*exp(-x/h1)) + (A2*exp(-x/h2)))
```

My code looks as follows

```
f <- as.formula(y ~ (C + (A1*exp(-x/h1)) + (A2*exp(-x/h2))))
nls_b <- nls(f, data = df, start = list(C = 0.140, A1 = 0.051, h1 = 586.772, A2 = 0.166, h2 = 33.323))
summary(nls_b)
b_opt <- predict(nls_b, newdata=df)
```

Now I have plotted the model predicted values with the observed values against x as

```
plot(y=df$y, x=df$x)
lines(y=b_opt, x=df$x, type='l')
```

Now how can I have the following plot
[image]

Data

```
df = structure(list(x = c(2L, 5L, 10L, 33L, 50L, 100L, 500L, 1500L
), y = c(0.34272, 0.34256, 0.30483, 0.25772, 0.21584, 0.19295, 
0.16144, 0.144)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Comment: Can we see `dput(df)` or a good chunk of it?

Comment: @AllanCameron Sorry for that. Now I have provided the data in `dput()` format. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Nice to have a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can first get a good plot of your model prediction by creating a smooth range of values in `x` and passing that to `newdata`:

```r
newdata <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 1500, 1))
newdata$y <- predict(nls_b, newdata)

plot(df)
lines(newdata)
```

[image]

Next, we take the log of the x scale and calculate a simple approximate numerical derivative for *dy / dlog(x)* (note this can be made arbitrarily accurate by changing the density of our `x` sequence in `newdata`):

```r
newdata$logx <- log(newdata$x)
newdata$dlogx <- c(0, diff(newdata$logx))
newdata$dy <- c(0, diff(newdata$y))
newdata$dy_dlogx <- newdata$dy / newdata$dlogx
```

So now we can plot your fitted curve on the log scale:

```r
with(newdata, plot(logx, y, type = "l"))
```

[image]

And the derivative like this:

```r
with(newdata, plot(logx, dy_dlogx, type = "l", col = "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you tell me why the derivative is coming in negative?

Comment: @BappaDas The line that nls fits to your points has a downsloping gradient throughout its range, so the derivative is negative. If you look at the data you supplied, it can only really have a negative gradient. Are you sure your data isn't reversed or negated?

Comment: I think the `nls` should have been done with logx rather than only x. I think then the derivative plot may become positive. Another thing, how can I have a equation for the minimum point of the derivative curve.

Comment: @BappaDas no, plotting y against log x still gives a downward sloping plot. The result in my answer looks like the one in your question but rotated 180 degrees. I think perhaps dy / d -log(x) would give you the same shape?.